# Jmeter odd and even threadNumbers

Tags: jmeter

I have to simulate a scenario where I want 50% to use one http request and the rest for another request. I tried using the IF controller to split by threadNumber i.e. send the odd thread numbers to one side and even to another. I tried using the condition in  IF controller in Jmeter as

```
 ${threadNum}' % 2 == '0'
```

and 
    '${threadNum}' %2 != '0'

I tried with around 10 users and I always see them going only into the odd queue i.e. ${threadNum}' % 2 == '0' is never satisfied. Am i doing it the right way?

Comment: Have you tried `${threadNum} % 2 == 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems here:

1. The JMeter function is `__threadNum` You lost the underscores somewhere. [Ref](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
2. What data type do you expect `${__threadNum}` to return? If it is a string, why would you do arithmetic (`%2`) on a string. If it is an int, why are you comparing it to a char (`'0'`)?

As an aside, do not compare strings in java using the `==` operator. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

---

That being said, if you want half the threads to use a second sampler, why not setup two thread groups with half the number of threads each, with one of the two http requests under the two thread groups?

Comment: To be more specific, i read the login ids and pwds for a set of users from a csv file. And I did use ${__threadNum} to get the thread number. I tried using a bean shell preprocessor to write it into  a variable ${threadNum}, because it did not work right when i tried directly using ${__threadNum}. Each user group has to hit a button from different pages and this button click uses the same functionality. So I am basically testing a functionality when called by different users at the same time from different pages. Is there a way to test this using JMeter

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), it will be much easier.

In regards to your question itself:

- Even thread numbers If Controller condition: `(${__threadNum} % 2 == 0)`
- Odd thread numbers If Controller condition: `(${__threadNum} % 2 != 0)`

If you're interested in more distribution options and ways of implementing them you're welcome to read [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide.